# Laravel 4 - Generate Nested json

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I'm fairly new to Laravel and I'm trying to extract nested json from a table in my database.

Basically I have a column in the table for a parent category and another columns for a subcategory.

I'd like to generate json similar to:

```
{
"Category 1":[
    {"sub category": "sub category 1"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 2"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 3"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 4"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 5"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 6"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 7"}
],
"Category 2":[
    {"sub category": "sub category 8"},
    {"sub category": "sub category 10"}
],
"Category 3": [
    {"sub category": "sub category 9"}
]
}
```

I'm not too sure how to go about this since I'm still getting to grips with the basics of the framework. I've tried the following which doesn't do the job.

```
Route::get('subcategories', function(){
  return Bikes::
  groupBy('parent_category')->
  lists('sub_category');
});
```

Any tips or pointers would be much appricated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Route::get('subcategories', function()
{
    $bikes = Bikes::groupBy('parent_category')->lists('sub_category');

    return $bikes->toJson();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No luck with that. It gives an error Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object. I think using toJson is probably redundant there since if I return the $bikes it will return json but not formatted the way I need it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out, it's not nested but it will work with angular the way I need it.

It was as simple as using orderBy like the below:

```
return Todo::OrderBy('parent_category')->select('parent_category', 'sub_category')->get();
```

This leaves me with:

```
 [
{
parent_category: "Chores",
sub_category: "Shop"
},
{
parent_category: "Chores",
sub_category: "Cleaning"
},
{
parent_category: "Work",
sub_category: "Development"
},
{
parent_category: "Work",
sub_category: "JS"
}
]
```

With that I can use angular to populate a select with opgroups using:

```
<select ng-model="todos" ng-options="t.sub_category group by t.parent_category for t in todos"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create models for self referencing tables like this:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

to use it:

```
$category = Category::find(1);
$categoryParent = $category->parent()->first(); // Gets parent category`
$categoryChildren = $user->children()->get(); // Gets the children`
```